# Magento: Add column in sales order grid without join

Tags: php, magento

I need to add a custom column in the sales order adminhtml grid.
Since I get the data for that grid from an external REST API by asking for data to a specific increment_id, I can't use the tutorials which are using a magento database to join the needed tables.

Is there another way like:

```
function rendering_sales_order_row_before($rowdata)  {
    $columnContent = $restapi->callByIncrementId($rowdata['increment_id']);
    $this->addColumn("Custom Column", $columnContent);
}
```

(This code should just illustrate my goal and I know that the solution will look completely different)

Is it possible to achieve that in magento in an elegant way?

EDIT: I'm using magento 1.9.2.1

Comment: my suggestion is if you post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ you will get better solutions

Comment: thanks, I gave it a try and hope that this is ok because of duplicate posting. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94169/add-column-in-sales-order-grid-without-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. I had a similiar problem. I solved it by using a **custom renderer** for my column.

First add your Sales Order Grid block *XX_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid*. Rewrite *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid*, extend it and add your column by overriding *_prepareColumns()* method.

```
$this->addColumn('my_column', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Column'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'index' => 'my_column',
        'type' => 'text',
        'order' => 'x',
    ));
```

Then add a custom renderer (*XX_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Widget_Renderer_MyColumn*) and extend *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract*.

Override the *render(Varien_Object $row)* method. Here you can do your specific operation (do your api request, manipulate in whatever way you want) and return the string. To build your request you want to use the data by param *$row*.

That should work :) If you need more info, just comment.

Comment: thanks, that helped me. togehter with the other answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94169/add-column-in-sales-order-grid-without-join/94175#94175 I managed to create my own renderer.

Comment: Glad it helped :) As I saw from your other question you try to avoid *rewriting the core grid*. Theres an option but plz create a new question.